# Navigation Bar logic implementation

Tags: iphone, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

I have taken navigation bar from controls and added one right bar button it is also taken from controls my requirement is I just want hide right bar button when view will appear and I have wrote drop down action for right bar button . I have an extra view controller called list view controller in this view controller I have 3 objects when I select one object then it is to be push to main view controller and right bar button is to be visible and when I click on right bar button selected object is to be add in drop down list can any one help me.

```
[self loadMenu];
[self btn];


self. navigationItem.title = @"sample";
[super viewDidLoad];


appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit confused on what you're asking for, but I believe that all you should have to do is

```
self.navigationController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.enabled = NO;
```

This will hide the button because it is set to the not-enabled set....

So, for going from one view to another, just do

```
[navController pushViewController:viewController animatedYES];
```

and to go backwards from that view do

```
[navController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

now to add it altogether:

```
 // creating UIViewController objects for reference later 
 View1 *view1 = [[View1 alloc] init];
 View2 *view2 = [[View2 alloc] init];

 // you are setting the view1 right navigation button in the view1 viewDidLoad
 self.navigationController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.enabled = NO;

 // now you are pushing to second view
 [navController pushViewController:view2 animated:YES];

 // now, in the view2 class, where you get the image that sends the 
 // user back to view 1, just do
 [view2.navController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

 // and then wherever you do the pop as shown above, you need to set the
 // view1 right bar button to enabled
 view1.navigationController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.enabled = YES;
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: thank u for ur repsonse actually i have 2 view controlls like viewcontrol1 and 2 . in view control one i have one right button when start my app the right bar button should me hide . the second thing is  in view control2 i have three objects(items in rows like images) in list when i select one image it is to be push to view controller1 and right bar button should be enable

Comment: you're welcome, but what you wanna do is when you push the view, you use [self.navigationController pushViewController:(UIViewController) animated:YES]; and when you want to go back just do popViewController

Comment: self.navigationController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.enabled = NO; i apply this but not working

Comment: thank u once again i wrote for push and pop its well but the problm is when i lanch my app barbutton item should be hide and in viewcontroller2 when i select row in that time in view controller1 barbutton item need to be visible

Comment: change the self.navigationController to whatever your navigationController variable name is..